# ASP.NET Identity - authenticate against MS account, don't maintain users database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

My use case is this: I have a website for which I am an admin. It's mostly public files (ASP.NET Web Pages, so just a bunch of `*.cshtml` files) but there are a couple of admin pages in the `/admin` folder.

What's the simplest way to only allow *me* (and just me) to access those admin scripts? Ideally, I'd like to say something like this:

```
# pseudocode; might go into web.config, some C# file, I don't care

path: admin
require-ms-account: me@example.com
```

And when I visited any admin page the site would validate that I am logged in using my MS account, and if not redirect me to a Live login form. What I **don't need / want** is user registration forms, password handling, relational database to store all this, etc.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.benday.com/2014/02/25/walkthrough-asp-net-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/

Comment: @Shoe - You do realize he asked for a solution WITHOUT a database...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch There is no database in that tutorial.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch All that is doing is configuring the project to be able to test the authentication locally.